# Calling a function every 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, function, timer, setinterval

Using `setTimeout()` it is possible to launch a function at a specified time:

```
setTimeout(function, 60000);
```

But what if I would like to launch the function multiple times? Every time a time interval passes, I would like to execute the function (every 60 seconds, let's say).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: get code to run every minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304471/javascript-get-code-to-run-every-minute)

Answer (score 443, accepted):

If you don't care if the code within the `timer` may take longer than your interval, use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

```
setInterval(function, delay)
```

That fires the function passed in as first parameter over and over.

A better approach is, to use `setTimeout` along with a `self-executing anonymous` function:

```
(function(){
    // do some stuff
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
})();
```

that guarantees, that the next call is not made before your code was executed. I used `arguments.callee` in this example as function reference. It's a better way to give the function a name and call that within `setTimeout` because `arguments.callee` is deprecated in ecmascript 5.

Comment: It's not possible for the next call to be made before the code finishes executing. The timer counts down asynchronously but the callback has to be queued. This means that your callback may (and probably will) fire after more than 60 seconds.

Comment: The difference is that setInterval will generally run the function x milliseconds after the **start** of the previous iteration, whereas the approach here will run the next iteration x milliseconds after the previous one **ended**

Comment: @Andy E's head, @Gareth: Gareth is right, that approach just avoids that loop-code will executed while another codeblock is still running.

Comment: True enough, you edited your answer after I wrote/while I was writing my comment.  What I said still stands though, there's no danger of the next callback executing before the previous one has finished.

Comment: Just as a note for others who may find this -- `clearInterval()` is a partner function to `setInterval()` and comes in handy if you want to cease your periodic function call.

Comment: Please note that setInterval executes the function for the first time after delay ms. So if you want to execute function immediately, and THEN repeat every delay, you should do:

    func();
    setInterval(func, delay);

Comment: Just to make it clear.. You should chose to use setInterval if the exact time will mater more then the possible function overlapings. In case you just want to keep a gap of 60 seckounds (+ what ever it takes to execute the function) then it would be better to use setTimeout inside recursive function with an "if" statment... so you can switch it of when ever you wish to. Something like: if(globalvar == true){setTimeout(.....,60000)}, than all you have to do to stop it to set the globalvar to false

Comment: I just don't get this arguments.callee thing. I have getRates() function but (function(){getRates();    setTimeout(getRates(), 10000);
})();
is not working :/

Comment: Wouldn't that just call the function one time after 6 seconds? 
```
(function() {
    const doIt = () => {
        console.log('do it!')
    }
    setTimeout(doIt, 5000)
})()
// waits 6 seconds and logs 'do it' one time. 
```
Clearly I am misunderstanding the answer as it is accepted with well over 300 upvotes. Can someone please fill me in? Thanks!

Comment: `arguments.callee` is not deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Your comment is somewhat confusing. Should it read *"`arguments.callee` is **now** deprecated and should not be used."* or *"`arguments.callee` is not deprecated and should **be** used."* or maybe *"`arguments.callee` is not deprecated **but don't use it**."*?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Typo... Should read "now", as you surmised.

Answer (score 82):

use the

```
setInterval(function, 60000);
```

---

**EDIT**: (In case if you want to stop the function after it is started)

Script section (which will automatically start)

```
<script>
var int=self.setInterval(function, 60000);
</script>
```

and HTML Code with button to stop

```
<!-- Stop Button -->
<a href="#" onclick="window.clearInterval(int);return false;">Stop</a>
```

Comment: In that case, how would you stop it from repeating after it had started repeating?

Answer (score 27):

A better use of [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386886/jandy)'s [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3138784/1249219) to implement a polling function that polls every `interval` seconds, and ends after `timeout` seconds.

```
function pollFunc(fn, timeout, interval) {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    interval = interval || 1000;

    (function p() {
        fn();
        if (((new Date).getTime() - startTime ) <= timeout)  {
            setTimeout(p, interval);
        }
    })();
}

pollFunc(sendHeartBeat, 60000, 1000);
```

**UPDATE**

As per the comment, updating it for the ability of the passed function to stop the polling:

```
function pollFunc(fn, timeout, interval) {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    interval = interval || 1000,
    canPoll = true;

    (function p() {
        canPoll = ((new Date).getTime() - startTime ) <= timeout;
        if (!fn() && canPoll)  { // ensures the function exucutes
            setTimeout(p, interval);
        }
    })();
}

pollFunc(sendHeartBeat, 60000, 1000);

function sendHeartBeat(params) {
    ...
    ...
    if (receivedData) {
        // no need to execute further
        return true; // or false, change the IIFE inside condition accordingly.
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you stop the polling from within `sendHeartBeat` ?

Comment: This is good example! When you use timers it harder to write unit tests, but with this approach - it's easy

Comment: Good answer. Please could you update one of the uses of new Date so that they are consistent, one uses (new Date).getTime() and the other (new Date()).getTime(). Both seem to work ok though

Comment: `interval` and `timeout` are in milliseconds, aren't they?

Answer (score 22):

In jQuery you can do like this.

```js
function random_no(){
     var ran=Math.random();
     jQuery('#random_no_container').html(ran);
}
           
window.setInterval(function(){
       /// call your function here
      random_no();
}, 6000);  // Change Interval here to test. For eg: 5000 for 5 sec
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="random_no_container">
      Hello. Here you can see random numbers after every 6 sec
</div>
```

Comment: The number renews more or less every 12 seconds - shouldn't this be one minute?

Comment: see comment `// Change Interval here to test. For eg: 5000 for 5 sec` Currently it is set to change every 6 seconds. use value 60000 for a minute

Answer (score 9):

```
setInterval(fn,time)
```

is the method you're after.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply call setTimeout at the end of the function. This will add it again to the event queue.  You can use any kind of logic to vary the delay values.  For example,

```
function multiStep() {
  // do some work here
  blah_blah_whatever();
  var newtime = 60000;
  if (!requestStop) {
    setTimeout(multiStep, newtime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`window.setInterval(func, time)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval).

Answer (score 6):

A good example where to subscribe a `setInterval()`, and use a `clearInterval()` to stop the forever loop:

```
function myTimer() {

}

var timer = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
```

call this line to stop the loop:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Call a Javascript function every 2 second continuously for 10 second.
>
> ```js
> var intervalPromise;
> $scope.startTimer = function(fn, delay, timeoutTime) {
>     intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
>         fn();
>         var currentTime = new Date().getTime() - $scope.startTime;
>         if (currentTime > timeoutTime){
>             $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
>           }                  
>     }, delay);
> };
>
> $scope.startTimer(hello, 2000, 10000);
>
> hello(){
>   console.log("hello");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function random(number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (number+1));
}
setInterval(() => {
    const rndCol = 'rgb(' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ',' + random(255) + ')';//rgb value (0-255,0-255,0-255)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = rndCol;   
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="test.js"></script>
it changes background color in every 1 second (written as 1000 in JS)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// example:
// checkEach(1000, () => {
//   if(!canIDoWorkNow()) {
//     return true // try again after 1 second
//   }
//
//   doWork()
// })
export function checkEach(milliseconds, fn) {
  const timer = setInterval(
    () => {
      try {
        const retry = fn()

        if (retry !== true) {
          clearInterval(timer)
        }
      } catch (e) {
        clearInterval(timer)

        throw e
      }
    },
    milliseconds
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here we console natural number 0 to ......n (next number print in console every 60 sec.) , using `setInterval()`

```
var count = 0;
function abc(){
    count ++;
    console.log(count);
}
setInterval(abc,60*1000);
```

Comment: A bit of explanation about how it solves the issue would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I see that it wasn't mentioned here if you need to pass a parameter to your function on repeat `setTimeout(myFunc(myVal), 60000);` will cause an error of calling function before the previous call is completed.

Therefore, you can pass the parameter like

```
setTimeout(function () {
            myFunc(myVal);
        }, 60000)
```

For more detailed information you can see the [JavaScript garden](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts).

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I favour calling a function that contains a loop function that calls a `setTimeout` on itself at regular intervals.

```js
function timer(interval = 1000) {
  function loop(count = 1) {
    console.log(count);
    setTimeout(loop, interval, ++count);
  }
  loop();
}

timer();
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to call-

1. `setInterval(function (){ functionName();}, 60000);`
2. `setInterval(functionName, 60000);`

above function will call on every 60 seconds.