# Repeat code every 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want repeat this code every 4 seconds, how i can do it with javascript or jquery easly ? Thanks. :)

```
$.get("request2.php", function(vystup){
   if (vystup !== ""){
      $("#prompt").html(vystup);
      $("#prompt").animate({"top": "+=25px"}, 500).delay(2000).animate({"top": "-=25px"}, 500).delay(500).html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery repeat function every 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/jquery-repeat-function-every-60-seconds)

Comment: And next time look for some identical questions too - just have a look to the right of this question

Comment: @Niklas, @BeingSimpler On the one hand, it's not great that the user has accepted no answers. However, the answers to the questions he's posted haven't been great, and no-one's ever asked him to accept answers before. He may not even know that it's possible. Your comments are a bit much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another possibility is to use `setTimeout`, but place it along with your code in a function that gets called recursively in the callback to the `$.get()` request.

This will ensure that the requests are a *minimum* of 4 seconds apart since the next request will not begin until the previous response was received.

```
 // v--------place your code in a function
function get_request() {
    $.get("request2.php", function(vystup){
       if (vystup !== ""){
          $("#prompt").html(vystup)
                      .animate({"top": "+=25px"}, 500)
                      .delay(2000)
                      .animate({"top": "-=25px"}, 500)
                      .delay(500)
                      .html("");
        }
        setTimeout( get_request, 4000 ); // <-- when you ge a response, call it
                                         //        again after a 4 second delay
    });
}

get_request();  // <-- start it off
```

Answer (score 37):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval) function

```
setInterval( fn , miliseconds )
```

From MDC docs:

> **Summary**
>
> Calls a function repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.
>
> **Syntax**

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

> where
>
> **intervalID** is a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval().
>
> **func** is the function you want to be called repeatedly.
>
> **code** in the alternate syntax, is a string of code you want to be executed repeatedly. (Using this syntax is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval())
>
> **delay** is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the setInterval() function should wait before each call to func. As with setTimeout, there is a minimum delay enforced.
>
> Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.

Example

```
// alerts "Hey" every second
setInterval(function() { alert("Hey"); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 29):

```
setInterval(function(){
  // your code...
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 20):

It's not too hard in javascript.

```
// declare your variable for the setInterval so that you can clear it later
var myInterval; 

// set your interval
myInterval = setInterval(whichFunction,4000);

whichFunction{
    // function code goes here
}

// this code clears your interval (myInterval)
window.clearInterval(myInterval);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upvoted for only answer how how to clearInterval. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
const milliseconds = 4000 

setInterval(
  () => { 
  // self executing repeated code below

}, milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Call a Javascript function every 2 second continuously for 20 second.
>
> ```js
> var intervalPromise;
> $scope.startTimer = function(fn, delay, timeoutTime) {
>     intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
>         fn();
>         var currentTime = new Date().getTime() - $scope.startTime;
>         if (currentTime > timeoutTime){
>             $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
>           }                  
>     }, delay);
> };
>
> $scope.startTimer(hello, 2000, 10000);
>
> hello(){
>   console.log("hello");
> }
> ```