# How would I make this function repeat?

Tags: javascript, random, repeat

I'm making a random character generator, and I have everything except for the repeat function; I'm trying to get it to repeat every 1-5 seconds.

```js
function makeid(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()_+=-,.<>/?{}[]|';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    } return result;
}
console.log(makeid(8));
```

Comment: This is javaSCRIPT not java

Comment: Please decribe what your problem is or where exactly you have a problem. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat code every 4 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403075/repeat-code-every-4-seconds)