# setTimeOut() or setInterval() . 4 methods to apply same thing. which is best?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, anonymous-function

I am displaying a countdown watch with respect to a given endtime.

although its working perfect but i want to know which is best methods to apply.

below is my countdown function.

```
  var timerId;
  var postData = {endDate : endDate, tz : tz};  
  var countdown = function()
    { 
      $.ajax({
               type : 'post',
               async : false,
               timeout : 1000,
               url : './ajax_countdown.php',
               data : $.param(postData),
               dataType : 'json',
               success : function (resp){
                  $('#currentTime').html(resp.remainingTime);
               }
            }); 
     }
```

what i want is that function (countdown) shoud be called *automatically after every 1 second* and if it does not execute/completed within 1 second then cancel the current ajax and start a new ajax call.

now I found there are **4 working methods**

#### method 1: using *setInterval() with window* object

```
window.setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

#### method 2 : using *setInterval()* independently

```
setInterval(function() {countdown()}, 1000);
```

#### method 3 :  using *setTimeOut* inside the function an call other function to intialize main function

```
var countdown = function() { 
     $.ajax({ //ajax code });
     timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 5000); // assign to a variable
 }

function clockStart() {  
        if (timerId) return
        countdown();
}
clockStart(); // calling this function
```

#### method 4 : using *anonymous function call*

```
var countdown = function() { 
     $.ajax({ //ajax code });
     timerId = setTimeout(countdown, 5000);
 }
  (function(){
         if (timerId) return;
         countdown();
})();
```

Please tell me

- What is con and pro of each method and which one is best/right method?
- Should i use `clearTimeOut()` or `clearInterval()` ?

**References**

#### http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

#### [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/jquery-repeat-function-every-60-seconds)

#### http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

Comment: I would consider 1 and 2 to be the same, with 1 being a cleaner approach. Similar for 3 and 4... whether you use an immediate function or not is more a matter of preference. I would call `countdown` immediately, no need to create an additional function.

Comment: @FelixKling yup, that extra `function()` block is completely unnecessary, as is the `window.` qualifier (mostly).

Comment: @FelixKling so you are suggesting #1.

Comment: @diEcho I suggest using #1 as well, there is never any reason to wrap a function in an anonymous function like that.

Comment: @diEcho: Only as "better" way compared to #2. But as I said, it's the same for me, the second one just appears to be a bit more convoluted. But whether to choose `setInterval` or `setTimeout` is a different question...

Comment: @diEcho - This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrGWz/1/) shows why delta timing is better than `setInterval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The benefit of using #1 over #2 is that the `window` reference removes the chance of a scope variable overwriting `setInterval`.

```
// When out of global scope...
function setInterval() {

}

window.setInterval(foo, 100); // still calls the "correct" setInterval
```

There's no difference between wrapping the call to `countdown` in a function (#1, #2). #2 gives you greater flexibility as you can also call other functions/ pass arguments etc (although it's obviously trivial to swap from #1 to #2 if this becomes the case).

#4 saves you having to declare a function `clockStart`, other than that, it's the same as #3.

Use `clearTimeout` if you used `setTimeout`, and `clearInterval` if you used `setInterval`...

You should also be aware of how `setTimeout` and `setInterval` work differently. There's an amazing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval/731625#731625) which explains that...

As for what I'd use? I'd use #2.

Comment: where do i write `clearInterval()` or `cleartimeOut()` respectively

Comment: What if `window` is a scope variable and not the global. The main point about them is the useless creation of an anonymous function imo.

Comment: @Matt you are suggesting #2, whereas FelixKling  suggesting #1

Comment: @diEcho: It's `clearTimeout`, not `cleartimeOut`. Put them whereever you need to clear the timeout or interval? You need to pass it the value `setTimeout/setInterval` returned.

Comment: @diEcho: I don't know what you mean? If you need to cancel the interval for any reason, call `clearInterval`, if you don't, then... don't.

Comment: @Esailija: Heh, good point. All the different implementations are swings and roundabouts TBH, you've really got to nit-pick to choose the "best" one.

Comment: @Matt : my assumption : "If the execution is impossible, `setInterval()` is queued.so  we use `clearInterval()`."  is this right?

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't use any of your methods. The reason is `setTimeout` and `setInterval` [do not guarantee that your code will execute after the specified delay](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). This is because JavaScript is single threaded.

If I need to call a function only once after a specified delay then I use `setTimeout`. However if I need to call a function after a fixed interval of time then I do not use `setInterval`. Instead I make use of [delta timing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing). Here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/2056987).

The advantage of using delta timing is that your code will execute closer to the fixed interval of time you specify. It corrects itself. Creating and using a delta timer is simple. For example your code would be written as follows:

```
var timer = new DeltaTimer(function (time) {
    $.ajax({
        // properties
    });

    if (time - start >= 5000) timer.stop();
}, 1000);

var start = timer.start();
```

The above delta timer is better than `setInterval` (method 1), makes use of `setTimeout` (method 2) but also corrects itself, starts the timer using a function (method 3), and doesn't pollute the scope with a special `clockStart` function (method 4).

In addition you can easily get the exact time the function is called after the timer starts as the time the function is called is passed as an argument to the function. The timer also has a `stop` method to stop the timer. To start it again call `start` again.

**Edit:**

If you want to make the `DeltaTimer` look more like `setInterval` (start the timer automatically) you may implement a spawn function as follows:

```
DeltaTimer.spawn = function (render, interval) {
    var timer = new DeltaTimer(render, interval);

    var start = timer.start = function (start) {
        return function () {
            render.start = start();
        };
    }(timer.start);

    start();

    return timer;
};
```

Then you may automatically create and start the `DeltaTimer` as follows:

```
var timer = DeltaTimer.spawn(function countdown(time) {
    $.ajax({
        // properties
    });

    if (time - countdown.start >= 5000) timer.stop();
}, 1000);
```

Thus `var timer = DeltaTimer.spawn(funct, delay);` is equivalent to `var interval = setInterval(funct, delay);` and `timer.stop();` is equivalent to `clearInterval(interval);`. I guess that's as much as you can automate it.

Comment: +1;  you really draw very good concept. but tell me how do i call this function directly. i dont want to call it. it shoud execute automatically

Comment: @diEcho - When you say that it should execute automatically what part of the above script are you trying to automate? There's not much room for automation but you may always create a [factory function](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.constructors "JavaScript Garden") and use that instead.

Comment: i means that `countdown` function should start as well as page load. i dont want to initialize it with any event.

Comment: @diEcho - I edited my answer to describe how to start the timer automatically.

Answer (score -1):

if you are creating countdown then why u don't use jquery plugin and customize it according to your requirements? Checkout here

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/05/jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Comment: I have read this already. this is not useful in my case. i need to change each page as per user's timezone.