# How to run a delay function for 5 times in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a delay function for five seconds in JavaScript which will print "Hello" in the console after every second for five times.

**Similar Python Code:**

```
from time import delay

for I in range(5):
    print("Hello")
    delay(1)
```

The above code will print "Hello" five times with one second delay between each print.

Now I want to do similar kind of operation in JS.

Now in JS we have `setTimeout` function which will call a function after after a specified time. The following code will print "Hello" in the console after 1 second interval.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
      console.log("Hello"); 
     }, 1000);
```

How can I run this code that will print 'Hello' in the console five times with an one second delay between each print?

**NB:** I tried to pass this function inside a for loop, but it did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624078/repeating-settimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
var count = 5;

printWithDelay();

function printWithDelay() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Hello");

    count--;

    if (0 < count) {
      printWithDelay();
    };
  }, 1000);
};
```

In JavaScript, 'setTimeout' runs after the code that follows it, so the next iteration of the loop needs to be called from within the callback function for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval`, this should get your job done!

`const test = setInterval(() => console.log("Hello"), 1000);`

And then after 5seconds remove interval

`setTimeout( () => clearInterval(test), 5000)`

```js
const test = setInterval(() => document.body.innerText += "Hello", 1000);
setTimeout( () => clearInterval(test), 5000);
```

NOTE: The first `console.log()` will happen after a second, if you want it immediately just put one `console.log()` outside the `setInterval`.

Comment: @yochanansheinberger Ya I posted the answer by mistake while I was typing, I've added that in

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, unlike PHP and Python, is asynchronous. The event loop is sensitive to anything that blocks it. However, there are ways to achieve what you want.

#### `setInterval`

With setInterval, you can build a wrapper it and use it.

```js
function repeatFunction(func, delay, repeat) {

  let counter = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {

    if (repeat !== counter) {
      func();
      counter++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, delay);

}


repeatFunction(() => console.log(5), 1000, 4)
```

#### `async/await` syntax

The other option is using `async/await` with Promises (recommended)

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}


(async() => {

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
  
  console.log('done')

})();
```