# auto load data from database using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to display newly inserted data from database. I found the below code from another question and it does what I want but it only shows the data when clicked. So can someone tell me how can I make the data auto load every 5 secs?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#display").click(function() {                

  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "second.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
    }

});
 });
});

</script>

<input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data" />
<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "second.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (response) {
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
                setTimeout(load, 5000)
            }
        });
    }

    load(); //if you don't want the click
    $("#display").click(load); //if you want to start the display on click
});
```

Comment: Hi arun your code will hit for every 5 seconds. even if there is no action we are sending unnecessary request to server for every 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `setTimeout`:

```
success: function(response){                    
    $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
    setTimeout(success, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function setTimeout as a timer to trigger. For detail, please look at below code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadData();
    });

    var loadData = function() {
        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "second.php",             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
                setTimeout(loadData, 5000); 
            }

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery's setInterval() or setTimeout() inside onload();
refer to the following questions, its answer explains well what you need exactly.

[Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/jquery-repeat-function-every-60-seconds)