# adding base url in javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i'm having a problem of adding my base url in javascript to load images (for effect), here is the code

```
 $(function(){

        $.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery({
            containment:"#home",
            timer:4000,
            effTimer:700,
            controls:"#controls",
            grayScale:false,
            shuffle:false,
            preserveWidth:false,
            effect:"slideDown",
            effect:{enter:{top:"-100%",opacity:1},exit:{top:0,opacity:0}, enterTiming:"ease-in", exitTiming:"ease-in"},



             images:[
             "/css/login/images/1.jpg",
             "/css/login/images/2.jpg",
             "/css/login/images/3.jpg"
             ],

            onStart:function(){},
            onPause:function(){},
            onPlay:function(opt){},
            onChange:function(opt,idx){},
            onNext:function(opt){},
            onPrev:function(opt){}
        });


    });
```

my codeigniter base url is localhost/project, so those links in javascript should be like localhost/project/css/login/images/1.jpg

appreciate the help, thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you define a variable like `base_url = "localhost/project/"` and use that in front of your images.

Comment: Please see first part of [this](http://goo.gl/fG39rc) answer, it explains the problem you are facing.

Comment: @kyslik i can't, because this code is in a javascript file, not html file

Comment: Isn't your js file called by a view in codeigniter? if so, the answer mentioned by @Kyslik perfectly solves your problem as the variable declared inside the script tags will be available for every piece of JavaScript loaded after it regardless of its origin.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that is to have a variable inside a script tag before you load your javascripts.

Add this at the header of the view that loads the javascript file which needs the base url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//A global variable which may hold any server variables
var ServerVariables = {
    baseUrl:"<?php echo $this->config->base_url() ?>"
}
</script>
```

Then you can load your scripts and the base URL will be available through the variable you declared before:

```
images:[
         ServerVariables.baseUrl + "/css/login/images/1.jpg",
         ServerVariables.baseUrl + "/css/login/images/2.jpg",
         ServerVariables.baseUrl + "/css/login/images/3.jpg"
         ],
```

**EDIT:** As stated by @Kyslik, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741035/calling-a-php-function-using-ajax-after-interval-of-time/20741717#20741717) answer seems to be the right one for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_url(url){
   return "localhost/project/"+url;
}

images:[
             my_url("/css/login/images/1.jpg"),
             my_url("/css/login/images/2.jpg"),
             my_url("/css/login/images/3.jpg")
             ],
```