# Infinite java script loop

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some simple functions using javascript, and I need to create an infinite loop that calls the getMessage() function every 5 seconds. Is there an easy method in achieving this? I searched online and I found that this can be done using the settimeout function. Any suggestions on how to use this? Thanks.
Here is this code I created till now...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    getMessage();
});

function getMessage() {

    alert("Hello World");

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Comment: Use `setInterval()` instead

Comment: Use a recursive loop with a setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` will only alert once, `setInterval` is what you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(getMessage, 5000);
});

function getMessage() {

    alert("Hello World");

}
```

To stop the interval:

```
var interval = window.setInterval(getMessage, 5000);
window.clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getMessage() {
  document.write("Hello World");
}

function go() {
  getMessage();
  setTimeout(go, 5000);
}

// $(document).ready(function () {
  go();
// });
```

```js
function getMessage() {
  document.write("Hello World");
}

function go() {
  var lastRun = -5000;
  
  (function tick(now) {
    if(now - lastRun >= 5000) {
     lastRun = now;
     getMessage();
   }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }());
}

// $(document).ready(function() {
  go();
// });
```