# How do I get a function to repeat itself in all infinity?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I want the function "timedText" to repeat itself, how is that possible?
So here is my code that I want to go around for ever, how do I fix that?

```
function timedText() {

  setTimeout(myTimeout1, 0)

  setTimeout(myTimeout2, 500)

  setTimeout(myTimeout3, 1000)

  setTimeout(myTimeout4, 1500)

}
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout will only be called once . You should use setInterval for infinite repetitions .

```
setInterval(myTimeout , 500)
```

Comment: `var interval = setInterval(myTimeout , 500); stopInterval(interval);` to stop