# Passing data between XML Views in SAPUI5

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

I have two views. View1 and View2. I am using View1 to get the parameters from the input field, and display data in View2 based on those parameters. Now I cam confused on how to pass data among the views. Can anybody please give me insights towards it, and with working code, and what each line does?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance if you have the Input field in View1.view.xml as this:

```
 <Input id="id" value="Initial Value" editable="true" />
```

you can get the field value in the respective Controller say, View1_cont.controller.js and set the model, which can be retrieved in any other controller later.

```
var oData = {
    input: this.getView().byId("id").getValue()
};
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"modelName");
```

Now in the second view's controller, say View2_cont.controller.js, the values can be retrieved and a view element with id "text" is set as shown below:

```
var oData = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("modelName").getData();
this.getView().byId("text").setValue(oData.input);
```

The text element in View2.view.xml is:

```
 <Text id="text"/>
```

Comment: What if I have multiple input fields? What changes do I make to var oData, to add them as well? Sorry I am bit weak in JS. And many many thanks for the answer.

Comment: var oData = {
    input1: this.getView().byId("id1").getValue(),  input2: this.getView().byId("id2").getValue(),  input3: this.getView().byId("id3").getValue()
}; and so on! Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, had guessed, sorry for being lazy! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Also in case I am using a select instead of just Text, I would like to retrieve the selected element. How can I get it's value?

Comment: this.getView(...).byId(...).getValue is not a Function

Comment: What UI control are you using? For example, if it is a Label then this would not work as Label does not have the Value property. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128056/sapui5-this-getview-byid-setvalue-is-not-a-function You should be using getText/setText instead. Please refer to the UI explored guide for further details on UI elements: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/