# How to call an API continuously from server side itself in Node js/Express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to call an API continuously from server side itself, so that it is called 24/7 every second. How can I achieve this?

I tried it as shown below in server.js, but getting 'TypeError: request.put is not a function'.

```
app.get('/',function(request,response){
    setInterval(function(){
        request.put('http://localhost:4242/changepaidstatus', function(error,response){
            if (error){
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` will let you repeat some function every second.

```
setInterval(() => {
    // will execute every second
}, 1000);
```

As for calling the API, you can use the [`request()` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to make any http request you would like.  Here's an example from [their doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request):

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

Comment: getting 'TypeError: request.put is not a function'.

Comment: @G.Mounika - I can't exactly help you with code I can't see.  Did you properly install the request library using NPM?  `request.put()` works just fine if you do things properly, so apparently your code (which I can't see) has an error in it.