# how to make a timer run again and again in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, timer

i want to make a 20 seconds countdown timer, when timer comes to zero it refreshes `iframe`. and then after refreshing `iframe` timer again comes to 20 seconds and after it comes 0 it again refreshes `iframe`. how can i do this, i have a js timer script which refreshes the `iframe` but i don't know how to make this script run again and again.

```
<script>
var tT;
var timer=20;
var stop;
$(document).ready(function(){
    tT=document.getElementById('timer');
    tT.value=timer;
    stop=setInterval(function(){
        if(timer>0){
            timer--;
            tT.value=timer;
        }else{
           clearInterval(stop);
    }},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('timer').value = timer;
     document.getElementById('exchanger').src = document.getElementById('exchanger').src;

    },20000);
});
</script>
```

Iframe :-

```
<input id="timer" value="20" type="text" size="2" readonly style="border:none;background:transparent;width:18px;text-align:center">
```

Comment: Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` like you have done before.

Comment: And please always format your code. If it gets longer and longer, itisdifficulttofollowifyoudontdoso.

Comment: ok, I am new here so please don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Albzi's suggestion  (who commented on my question), I
Used setInterval instead of setTimeout and It worked!

the final script is:

```
var tT;
var timer=20;
var stop;
$(document).ready(function(){
tT=document.getElementById('div-ID');
tT.value=timer;
stop=setInterval(function(){
if(timer>0){
timer--;
tT.value=timer;
}else{clearInterval(stop);
}},1000);
setInterval(function(){ // I changed setTimeout here
document.getElementById('Iframe-ID').src = document.getElementById('Iframe-ID').src;
timer=20;
},20000);
});
```

and HTML: `<div id="Div-ID"></div>`
Iframe: `<iframe id="Iframe-ID" src="source-url"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setInterval(function, delay)
```

Here is the code for your function

```
(function(){
// do some stuff
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 20000);
```

})();

for reference, this question is already marked here on below link:
[Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to help you out:

```js
function loadlink() {
  $('#iframeId')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  $(".timer").text(count)
  count++;
  if (count == 20) {
    loadlink() // this will run after every 20 seconds
    count = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer"></div>


<iframe id="iframeId" class="myframe" name="myframe" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: $('#iframeId')[0].contentWindow.location.reload(true);
"#" is necessary before iframe id?

Comment: Yes, since its an iframe, it is necessary.

Comment: As an alternative, you can remove the iframe and refresh a DIV container. Its easy to tweak this code for DIV container.

Comment: It is not working on 000webhost.com. I had a solution sometime ago but I have lost it, the solution was using for loop and it worked great but I deleted the script by mistake