# How can I refresh a jascript function automatically?

Tags: javascript, html

I need function save data to refresh automatically after 5seconds,how can I do it...,

```
<body  onload="savedata();">

<script type="text/javascript">

 setInterval(savedata, 5000); 


 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">



function savedata() {

<script/>
```

Comment: `setInterval(savedata, 5000)`

Comment: Make sure you close the `</script>` tag also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the function by reference, not the string :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(savedata, 5000);

function savedata() {

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ savedata() }, 5000);

function savedata() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once:

```
<script>
setTimeout(savedata, 5000)
function savedata(){}
</script>
```

Every 5 secs:

```
<script>
function savedata(){}
let myInterval = setInterval(savedata, 5000)
//To stop
clearInterval(myInterval)
</script>
```