# how to set timeout each time a function is called

Tags: javascript, if-statement, timeout

I'm trying to create an if statement which sets a timeout when a function is called:

```
    var timeOutID;

    if (//function1 is called) {
      timeOutID = setTimeout(function1, 30000);
    }
```

The idea is that the function gets repeatedly called after 30 seconds, but the timeout can be reset at any point if function is called (e.g. a button is clicked). How can this be accomplished? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Comment: [This answer talks about cancelling the timeout too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3138761/542251)

Comment: I've made this functionality a few days ago for a slightly different purpose but you'll get the idea [from this Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/vubukazoha/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do something repeating at a set interval, `setInterval` may be a better way to go. It will call a method after every X milliseconds if you don't cancel it.

Here is a basic example of reseting the interval whenever a button is clicked. In the log you will see that when you don't click the button a new log line appears every 5 seconds. When you click on the button the next line will take longer to appear after which they will appear again every 5 seconds.

I used 5 seconds instead of 30 so you don't have to wait that long to see the effect of pressing the button.

```js
const
  resetButton = document.getElementById('reset'),
  confirmationMessage = document.getElementById('confirmation'),
  intervalDuration = 5000;
  
let
  intervalId = null
  lastCallTime = new Date();
  
function resetInterval() {
  // Stop the current interval...
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // and start a new interval.
  startInterval();
}

function startInterval() {
  // Set an interval, it will call logTimeSinceLastCall every X seconds. 
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    logTimeSinceLastCall();
  }, intervalDuration);
}

function logTimeSinceLastCall() {
  // Hide the message that the interval has been reset.
  
  confirmationMessage.classList.add('hidden');
  const
    // Get the current time.
    now = new Date(),
    // Substract the time from the last call, the difference is the number of milliseconds passed.
    diff = now.getTime() - lastCallTime.getTime();
  
  // Log a line to the console for some visual feedback.
  console.log(`Last call was ${diff}ms ago`);
  // Update the time stamp of the last time this method was called.
  lastCallTime = now;
}
  
function onResetClicked(event) {
  resetInterval();
  // Show the message that the button has been clicked.
  confirmationMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
}
  
// Whenever the button is clicked, reset the interval.
resetButton.addEventListener('click', onResetClicked);

// Start the initial interval.
startInterval();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="reset">Reset interval</button>
<p id="confirmation" class="hidden">
  The interval has been reset.
</p>
```