# Javascript Chrome console while

Tags: javascript, while-loop, google-chrome-console

I was trying to create a loop in Chrome console with Javascript that executes the same function all the time. Instead it doesn't output anything and it actually just increases Chromes memory size until it crashes. Any advice on what's going wrong here?

```
while(true){
    window.setTimeout(function (){
        console.log("Hello");
    }, 4000)}
```

Comment: `while(true) {}` with no `break;` creates an infinite loop. My advice: Don't do that.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, I need it to run forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Comment: js is single threaded your code execution will block the hole event loop and no other event will ever be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an immense number of `setTimeout` events, all of which are created immediately in rapid succession and scheduled to be invoked 4000 ms after their creation.

Seems like you're  looking for `.setInterval()` to perform a continuous invocation.

```js
window.setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}, 4000);
```

---

To do it with `setTimeout`, you'd still not use any kind of imperative loop. You'd have the callback set up another `setTimeout` when it runs.

```js
window.setTimeout(function f() {
  console.log("Hello");
  setTimeout(f, 4000);
}, 4000);
```

I gave the callback function the name `f` so that it could be used for the next timer.

---

In general, you don't "pause" your script. You schedule things to be done at a later time, and allow code to continue running until then. That's why you had a problem. The scheduled timer didn't pause anything, so the loop just keep running at full speed.

Comment: Seems to be working now with your code. Thanks! Do you think this will fill up RAM eventually?

Comment: @sander: No, the event is put in the event queue and is removed when invoked.