# How to Get a JSON URL With JQuery and Output Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a very simple script using JQuery that will take a JSON dataset from a URL, filter the JSON using a hard-coded parameter and output the text from some of the data from the resulting filtered dataset. I would prefer to use JQuery, but am open to JavaScript options as well. This particular example is using the NYC CitiBike station status JSON feed and filtering using the "station_id" variable of 168 (the first station in the set).

I would also like this to refresh the query (or the div) every 30 seconds without refreshing the entire HTML page.

Below is an example of what I am attempting to accomplish. It should convey the general sense of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="output"></div>

    <script>
    $.getJSON('https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json', function(data) {
    var objects = data.stations.filter(function(v){return v.station_id==168});        

        var text = `Station ID: ${objects.station_id}<br>
            Bikes Available: ${objects.num_bikes_available}<br>
            Docks Available: ${objects.num_docks_available}'


        $(".output").html(text);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `filter()` returns an array but you are treating result as a single object. Is that where your problem is?  You really haven't outlined specific problem or any errors

Comment: so, the issue that you are facing here is?

Comment: Your `text` variable is badly formatted. Apart from that, this code seems to be lifted from somewhere and doesn't emphasize any specific problem areas.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I am having difficulty returning a single object within the array within the JSON. So for example returning the value of 'num_bikes_available' within a single array (defined by 'station_id') within the dataset of the JSON data

Comment: @UdoE. not "lifted" from anywhere. Just my own attempt to create what I am looking for. My problem is really just trying to filter the JSON to return the one array for a single 'station_id'.

Comment: So if it is only going to be one result you can use `objects[0]` for that object. Can also change `filter()` to `find()` to return a single object instead of array

Comment: Or you can just attach `[0]` to the end of the filter line, before the semi-colon. You major problem here should the **refresh after 30seconds**. Am I right?

Comment: An array of even a single object is still an array and needs to be treated like one. Can't read object, read content at index 0 of object. Like this object[0].

Comment: If your question is "how can I do this every 30 seconds", the answer to [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138756/215552) will answer that (just replace the 6 with a 3, obviously), but it's not clear what your question is. You can [edit] your question to make it clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the single item you can use `find()` instead of `filter()`.

Also the array is in property `data.data.stations`

```
$.getJSON('https://gbfs.citibikenyc.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json', function(data) {
  var item = data.data.stations.find(function(v) {
    return v.station_id == 168
  });

  var text = `Station ID: ${item .station_id}<br>
            Bikes Available: ${item.num_bikes_available}<br>
            Docks Available: ${item.num_docks_available}`


  $(".output").html(text);

});
```

As for repeating this you can wrap it in a function and use `setInterval()` to call that function at whatever interval you need.

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wbp93sja/)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. The 'data.data.stations.find()' function was what was throwing me off. Thank you for sharing this very elegant solution!