# Jquery loop until web page is available?

Tags: jquery, loops

Using jquery / ajax I'm calling a php script which then runs a process which restarts apache2 on the server the pages are being supplied from.

I want the script to loop until a web page on the server is accessible (ie: apache2 has restarted) or x seconds expire.

Currently I use a `setTimeout(function(){}` with a timeout of 10 seconds. This works but I feel it could be problematic, or the timeout could happen when apache2 hasn't restarted.

Anyone any ideas how I can create a jquery loop checking if a page is accessible or not, or timeout after say 10 seconds ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run a function ever N seconds and test whether the server is availble. When it succeeds, cancel the interval timer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)