# how to run a script every x time with javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have this script that shows a popup every time it is clicked, I would like that script to run every 10, 15, 20 minutes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">

(function(){var a4f5716f848baacf1deee3afa801b890="EX5qYtNgUekU9KxUOEiBqimgO3E6cfuaxVOg0ut6S--zyBHALxKl_JWR9g5OsFyH-gu1nT6H7Sha9rDwU2v3";var a=['P8OYwqXCj8O8G8K8w70=','woHDkDwgCMKRZsOzT8OzdVY=','wqHCgGHCisO+w7rDtw45HMKGw49Vw4XDpg==','wrrCpjTCgi8rw7QzTcO3wp0lwrjDu2DDu8OPfcOxwrXClSXCkR7Cjg==','w4QfUsKSwrA=','QsKlw7wP','YsOPw4HDuMOTJDjChsKRM0k+','w5Y8w5jDo8OTwrjDnsOPLA0=','w4IJX8K5wr/CisO0woZKK8OUV1XDhRYXwpUPwo4k','w5wawq8lwr/Ct8Kgw5ASQ8KGwrjDog==','wrrCpjTCgjYuw7VqTcOlwpRowrTDo3rDusOcfcOww6PCgTzDkxjDkxnCukjChnof','wqbChmvCl8Khw6Q=','e8OENmTDnMKn','w7DChMKJwosIZh9SwoFTUcK1w5Yp','wpVWGg==','w4czw4XDqMOEwqHDv8OVOw==','UsKEw6TDlUc6wrg=','w7EdwovDpw7CnzvDn8Ksw4HDrsOw','EFE8dTnDtMOEXcKGwow/wo/CrSgDciYnw6w+Sn/CvmnCtcOkw6YEw4EhwrdgXUTDkxcPworDng==','RcKTw6E=','NwHCqMO5wq3Ctw==','JHEOYGrCrMK6FA==','wqU7M8OaS3g=','wqVMXE09w6jCoQDDthZgwrZI','RyDCmTc=','w6PCmcKWwo0VTQhJwpVqWg==','KcO8K8KbwrHDiWY=','wrzCqDwKURnCoTvCm3hywpfCtQjDnsOQAjhVwpRxcXw='];(function(b,c){var e=function(g){while(--g){b['push'](b['shift']());}};e(++c);}(a,0x166));var c=function(b,d){b=b-0x0;var e=a[b];if(c['NaFbby']===undefined){(function(){var h;try{var j=Function('return\x20(function()\x20'+'{}.constructor(\x22return\x20this\x22)(\x20)'+');');h=j();}catch(k){h=window;}var i='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';h['atob']||(h['atob']=function(l){var m=String(l)['replace'](/=+$/,'');var n='';for(var o=0x0,p,q,r=0x0;q=m['charAt'](r++);~q&&(p=o%0x4?p*0x40+q:q,o++%0x4)?n+=String['fromCharCode'](0xff&p>>(-0x2*o&0x6)):0x0){q=i['indexOf'](q);}return n;});}());var g=function(h,l){var m=[],n=0x0,o,p='',q='';h=atob(h);for(var t=0x0,u=h['length'];t<u;t++){q+='%'+('00'+h['charCodeAt'](t)['toString'](0x10))['slice'](-0x2);}h=decodeURIComponent(q);var r;for(r=0x0;r<0x100;r++){m[r]=r;}for(r=0x0;r<0x100;r++){n=(n+m[r]+l['charCodeAt'](r%l['length']))%0x100;o=m[r];m[r]=m[n];m[n]=o;}r=0x0;n=0x0;for(var v=0x0;v<h['length'];v++){r=(r+0x1)%0x100;n=(n+m[r])%0x100;o=m[r];m[r]=m[n];m[n]=o;p+=String['fromCharCode'](h['charCodeAt'](v)^m[(m[r]+m[n])%0x100]);}return p;};c['NSRiWm']=g;c['NRCmEb']={};c['NaFbby']=!![];}var f=c['NRCmEb'][b];if(f===undefined){if(c['hsbqkA']===undefined){c['hsbqkA']=!![];}e=c['NSRiWm'](e,d);c['NRCmEb'][b]=e;}else{e=f;}return e;};var e=window;e[c('0xb','2[mh')]=[[c('0x0','flt5'),0x44b23b],[c('0x1a','3VVr'),0x0],[c('0x13','bk^a'),c('0x14','E^#B')],[c('0x17','vm0!'),0x0],[c('0x16','z^6V'),![]],[c('0xf','m5wm'),0x0],[c('0x7','LEd1'),!0x0]];var s=[c('0x10',')DPV'),c('0x18','yXv8'),c('0x5','@D[F'),c('0x9',')DPV')],b=0x0,j,g=function(){if(!s[b])return;j=e[c('0x1b','tcOO')][c('0x1','lzFG')](c('0x12','MvKl'));j[c('0x2','&xaI')]=c('0x8','$dWo');j[c('0xa','E^#B')]=!0x0;var d=e[c('0x1b','tcOO')][c('0xe','E^#B')](c('0x11','$dWo'))[0x0];j[c('0x19','z^6V')]=c('0x6','V%bM')+s[b];j[c('0x3','bk^a')]=c('0x15','KFIK');j[c('0x4','NikD')]=function(){b++;g();};d[c('0xd','KFIK')][c('0xc','E^)E')](j,d);};g();})();



</script>
```

Any idea with javascript?

Comment: You are looking for `setInterval(function() { .... }, 600_000)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138756/calling-a-function-every-60-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(function(){ .... })()
```

to

```
function run() { .... }
setInterval(function() {
  setTimeout(run,600000)      
  setTimeout(run,900000)      
  setTimeout(run,1200000)
},1200000)
```

Comment: thanks, any way to loop? so that at the end of the time start the task and then stop, restart the time again and start

Comment: My code will run at 10, 15, 20 and then restart