# Insert JavaScript Timer within this script

Tags: javascript, timer

Where would you insert this JavaScript Timer on this script? Right now the Quotes Page refresh is manual, I want to set a Timer with 60 seconds to auto change the page. Here is the current script below,

The script is built, I just need to add a Timer to auto-refresh page.

```
const generateQuote = function() {
  const quotes = [
  {
      quote: "Do not pity the dead, Harry. Pity the living, and, above all those who live without love.",
      author: "Albus Dumbledore"
  },
  {
      quote: "It is impossible to manufacture or imitate love",
      author: "Horace Slughorn"
  },
  {
      quote: "Being different isn't a bad thing. I means that you are brave enough to be yourself.",
      author: "Luna Lovegood"
  },
  {
    
  }
];

let arrayIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  document.getElementById("quotes").innerHTML = quotes[arrayIndex].quote;
  document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = quotes[arrayIndex].author;

}
window.onload = function() {
  generateQuote();
  document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener('click', generateQuote);
}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript.

Comment: See also [Calling a function every 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3138756/215552)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, create a `setTimeout` function (that loops) which can be cleared (using `clearTimeout`) and rescheduled — if the user clicks the button:

```js
const elQuote = document.querySelector("#quote");
const elAuthor = document.querySelector("#author");
const elGenerate = document.querySelector("#generate");
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "Do not pity the dead, Harry. Pity the living, and, above all those who live without love.",
    author: "Albus Dumbledore"
  },
  {
    quote: "It is impossible to manufacture or imitate love.",
    author: "Horace Slughorn"
  },
  {
    quote: "Being different isn't a bad thing. I means that you are brave enough to be yourself.",
    author: "Luna Lovegood"
  },
];

// Quotes logic:

let tOut;

const generateQuote = () => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  const quote = quotes[rand];
  elQuote.textContent = quote.quote;
  elAuthor.textContent = quote.author;
  
  clearTimeout(tOut); // clear existing pending timeout
  tOut = setTimeout(generateQuote, 5000); // Schedule auto generate after 5 seconds
};

generateQuote();
elGenerate.addEventListener('click', generateQuote);
```

```html
<section>
  <blockquote id="quote"></blockquote>
  <address id="author" rel="author"></address>
  <button id="generate" type="button">Generate new quote</button>
<section>
```

With the above solution with good UX in mind, if the user clicks the *generate* button, a timeout that is pending will be cleared, the quote will be regenerated, and a new loop timeout loop will be rescheduled.